# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag() not finding the right fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sdk, fragment

I upgraded my app from SDK 26 to SDK 28 and it ruined my app's navigation. I have a central tabbed activity. In each tab, the flow of the app is managed by fragments. I have implemented the back press in a way that the previous fragment of the current tab is shown. The back press code is:

```
   public void onBackPressed() {
        String name = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(
                fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();

        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);

        String tag = ((AppFragment) fragment).getPreceddingFragmentTag();

        Fragment frag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        removeFragment(fragment);
        replaceFragment(frag, tag);
    }
```

I pass the current fragment's tag to the next in its constructor which is then fetched by the `getPreceddingFragmentTag()` method in the above code.
I use one method to show new fragments on the screen as well as remove them when back is pressed. Here's the code for that:

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        loadedFragment = (AppFragment) fragment;
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(mContainerId, fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

I maintain the backstack to keep track of transactions and get the currently displayed fragment when the user presses back.
The remove fragment method is:

```
private void removeFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

My app works in the following manner:
The tab opens up a fragment that contains a list that takes the user to the next fragment upon item click; which is also a list, tapping on an item in the list takes the user to the item's detail fragment.

Here's the issue:

I go from the first fragment to the next, then to the item details and come back. It works perfectly the first time.

I tap on another item on the list in the first fragment, it shows the next fragment perfectly, I tap on an item for details and then press back. Instead of showing the fragment that it was supposed to show, it shows the fragment that was shown in the previous flow.

I have ruined days and nights on **stackoverflow**, **medium** and **Google Developers Documentation** and have found no solution. My app was working perfectly with SDK 26 and 28 ruined everything. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue happened with me as well. In my case this issue happened due to following library:

`androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`

Downgrade this library to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0`. This probably will fix your transaction issue. I am not sure if this is bug in library or they made any sort of improvement as i haven't found any particular notes in appcompat:1.1.0 release notes.